# Primefaces dialog position issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I am using primefaces v 8.0 I am facing an issue with p:dialog component it's position is not to the top and half of the dialog is not shown i've tried many things also tried to change CSS as follows :

```
.ui-dialog{
     top: 0px !important;
 }
```

following the code I use :

```
<p:dialog header="#{msg.image_description}" widgetVar="imageDescriptionDlg" id="imageDescriptionDlg"
                  dynamic="true"
                  showEffect="fade" width="70%" height="650" draggable="false"
                  hideEffect="fade">
            <div class="ui-g">
```

I am using the same component in other views but not facing this issue of dialog being down and part of it not shown as it is under the bottom of the screen

Comment: Can you please try with PrimeFaces 13?

Comment: it is not possible currently to upgrade to 13

Comment: I'm not asking to upgrade. I'm asking to try with 13. There are dialog issues fixed in 13. If it fixes your issue, it makes it easier for you to find and optionally back port to 8. See also https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Can you post the structure of the page with the problem? Do you use a theme/custom css? Do you try with the position tag?

Answer (score 0):

Two things...try to add these two properties to your dialog.

1. `fitViewport="true"` Dialog size might exceeed viewport if content is bigger than viewport in terms of height. fitViewport option automatically adjusts height to fit dialog within the viewport.
2. `responsive="true"` In responsive mode, dialog adjusts itself based on screen width.

I have a feeling one or both of these settings will solve your issues.

Doc reference for PF 8.0: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/dialog?id=dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
onShow="PF('widgetNameOfTheDialogHere').initPosition()"
```

to your p:dialog.